# Math symbols in listings

Tags: math, latex, listings

I have a problem with LaTeX – I don't know how to put mathematical equations and symbols in listings. I use the `listings` package and it's offers great looking listings, but it doesn't allow math symbols in `$ ... $`. Another package, `algorithms`, allows math, but listings doesn't look as good as with `listings` (the problem is that `algorithms` demands to get new line after every `if`, `then`, etc.)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use the option `mathescape` for your environment which gives you the ability to use the normal latex behavior of the $-signs. Try:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

For more info, take a look into the `listings` [package manual](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/).